# How to test isnumeric condition in hive?

Tags: sql, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, bigdata

I have data ID column ,it contains both numbers and letters, I want only numeric IDs list, is there any inbuilt condition for the same, I want to cast data latter.
I know in SQL as

```
 'CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([id])=1 THEN CAST([id] as int) ELSE 0 END [ID]'
```

what is the query in hive ? 

Please help on this.

Comment: what is exactly stuff on your query?

Comment: I have data in varchar datatype, I want to convert (cast) it into int type, only if it contains the numeric characters ..

Comment: Which Hive version are you using?

Comment: CDH 5.4 , in that hive has 1.1.0 version

Comment: How is this spark related ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this way

```
select CAST([id] as int) as id from tablename where ISNUMERIC([id])=1
```

Comment: Sorry, now in hive isnumeric function not there........I am facing problem with this function..

Comment: This answer is completely incorrect as isnumeric is not a Hive function.

Comment: incorrect answer. OP asked for hive example. In hive isnumeric is not available.

Comment: There is no `isnumeric`function in Hive, but similar functionality can be achieved in two ways with queries like `select count(*) from <tableName> where cast(<colName> as double) is not NULL` or using regular expressions like `select count(*) from <tableName> where <colName>  rlike '[^0-9]' ;`